# Celery doesn't recognize environment variable BROKER_URL

Tags: python, celery, pyramid

currently I am trying to run a Celery task within a pyramid file using pycelery with a Redis url which itself is an environment variable, so I try declaring it as follows
    `[celery]`
`BROKER_URL = ${REDIS_URL}`

but when I run it I get the error
[image]

which suggests that the `BROKER_URL` isn't recognizing the environment variable. But earlier in the file I'm able to declare
`redis.url = ${REDIS_URL}` just fine . Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately INI setting parsing is not harmonized across Python applications and libaries. The environment variable expansion usually happens on library level, not on INI parsing level.

Thus, `pyramid_redis` supports environment variables. But unless `pyramid_celery` adds explicit environment variable support, it doesn't happen.

[pyramid_celery repository is here](https://github.com/sontek/pyramid_celery). I suggest you add an issue regarding this. Meanwhile you can either configure Celery by hand in Python code (not using ini) or use hardcoded value.